# Postfix responds with 450 4.7.1 even though names resolve properly

Tags: postfix

The following is happening for reasons I do not understand.

Excerpt: from mail.log

> Dec 21 17:03:56 server postfix/smtpd[13014]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[**10.X.X.40**]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname, [**10.X.X.40**]; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=<**server.mydomain.de**>

Obviously my main.cf contains the following:

> smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, **reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname**

Checking reverse and forward DNS from the postfix machine yields correct results:

```
# dig -x 10.X.X.40

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;40.X.X.10.in-addr.arpa.                IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
40.X.X.10.in-addr.arpa. 3600    IN      PTR     server.mydomain.de.

# dig server.mydomain.de.

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server.mydomain.de.                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
server.mydomain.de. 3600    IN      A       10.X.X.40
```

As you can see, the reverse record for the connecting IP points to a servername, the A Record for this name points back to the correct IP and on top of that, this servername also matches the EHLO.

To make this even more interesting, the sending server queues up all those mails and then, every few days or weeks, the recieving server all of a sudden accepts all the mails for a few minutes without any configuration changes.

This only happens for those internal systems sending mails. The same postfix server happily receives mail from the Internet from each and every server (if it has correct DNS records and passes all other restrictions).

Comment: Postfix does not query DNS to determine the SMTP client hostname. Postfix uses the system library getnameinfo() and getaddrinfo() routines. What do you have in `/etc/hosts`?